# Rationalism as social control

Tags: politics, society, philosophy

I'm researching a bit for book idea and would like some input. Say I'm a dictator that would like to use rationalist dogma as a front to unify my country. Obviously, it wouldn't be using pure rationalism, but prima facie, my basic tenets would resemble rationalism. How could I distort a rationalist ideology to best control my constituency? And what fallacies would this distortion be the result of?

Comment: The obvious answer would be to put forth policies that everybody wants and agrees with. If you are the best choice to act as leader for this, everyone would support you without any fallacies needed.

Comment: I suppose an interesting corollary to that would be that a leader who would employ this method is not the best choice.

Comment: I think every ideology considers itself the only rational conclusion within the axioms provided by its value system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to distort a logical, rational argument in such a way that it's difficult to refute is to change axioms, or to use invalid axioms.

For example, the following statement is entirely logical:

> Pigs are birds.  Birds can fly.  Therefore, pigs can fly.

So the *logic* is sound - if pigs are birds, and birds can fly, then of course pigs can fly.  The reason the conclusion is wrong is because one of your axioms - pigs are birds - is false, and that invalidates your final conclusion.

So what your dictator needs to do is find an axiom that appeals to the people of his country, that they *want* to be true, and that's not easy to refute.  Emotional appeals work well here.  He can then use this as the basis for rational/logical arguments to assume power.  Attempts at going against the axiom will run into the emotional support, and it's not possible to invalidate the logic directly.

You have a few possibilities here for your false axioms.  A shared enemy (another country, or a minority) is a common one - humans seem to be hardwired for "us vs them", so creating an outside, [dehumanized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehumanization) enemy can be the basis behind your actions.

Comment: I believe we would say that your argument is **valid** (its premises do lead to its conclusion) but it is not **sound** (valid + all the premises are true).

Answer (score 4):

Most important, remember one thing: *emotion* is faster than rational thought. Fear is the fastest. For millions of years, this had evolutionary advantage. So load your propaganda with emotions, mostly fear of "others".

Then, easiest way would be to rationalize why your nationality is supreme over all others. Even better than invalid axioms, would work plausible, believable lies. Then you pull few well-proven tricks from nazi propaganda machine:

- Start with complete control over mass information system, and education. You want people who have no idea how much they do not know.
- then, if you repeat lie 1000 times, people start believe it - [Goebbels](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Joseph_Goebbels)
- Some lies have wild popularity: [If you are not with us, you are against us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You%27re_either_with_us,_or_against_us) - Used by Lenin, Mussolini, and surprisingly for Europeans, GW Bush
- Convenient enemy who is at fault if anything goes wrong. Better if it is close-by: some of your neighbor nations. To fight such permanent enemy, you of course need temporarily restrict freedom of speech and enforce censorship. And anyone who disagrees about restriction is not patriotic enough and suspicious - [McCarthyism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCarthyism).
- Most people will torture others to obey authority, as proven by [Milgram experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milgram_experiment)

Works like charm. Most people want to join someone who looks like a winner. read [1984](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four) if you haven't yet.

For people who grew up in such situation, decision to support you seems to be completely rational.